# Change number of Reviews on WooCommerce products on mobile

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, review

Good morning every one,

I wanted to know if it was possible to change the number of reviews display when we are on a mobile phone with woocomerce in wordpress.

I tried this : https://rich-snippets.io/woocommerce-review-args-hook/
to limit the number of comment but nothing works.

I use woocommerce on wordpress with the plugin "Customer Reviews for WooCommerce".

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS (media queries) as this is how the display for different devices is usually incorporated. This means however that reviews will get loaded and that reviews will always be shown based on the correct device.

If you explicitly would like to do the calculation before the page rendering, you could perhaps use e.g. [MobileDetect script](http://mobiledetect.net/) in combination with the article you mentioned.